# How to create a redistributable self contained binary distribution of a VM with VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, binary, virtualbox, virtualization, redistributable

Is it possible to create a self contained binary distribution of a VM with VirtualBox or some other tool?

My requirements:

- no VirtualBox install
- self contained binary/-ies to start and stop VM (with all VirtualBox environment support on it)
- *possibly* no administrator rights to start and stop the VM
- at least windows, but better if cross platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory it is possible to create a giant blob that bundles some kind of hypervisor which will first extract install along with the VM (disk, config. etc.) and then run itself and the extracted VM.

However, that is only theory. In practice, hypervisors are very complex pieces of software and require some sort of ring-0 access (kernel level) to talk directly with the CPU and other hardware and VirtualBox is no exception. So installing them, on any operating system that cares even a little bit about security, will require admin/root/supervisor access as you cannot install drivers and other kernel components otherwise.

If performance is of no concern, it may be possible to use an emulator like Qemu/Bochs which can work without ring-0 access. However, I'm not currently aware of any projects that have such self-extracting and runnable emulators for pre-baked VM images (even more so on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

As Tekn0 writes, it is required a low level access to the host OS layer.
I found the project [Portable VirtualBox](http://www.vbox.me/) which setups the host machine on the fly.
I tested it and it is not enough satisfactory. From the site:

> Note
>
> VirtualBox needs several kernel drivers installed and needs to start
>   several services: if the drivers and services are not already
>   installed you’ll need administrator rights to run Portable-VirtualBox.
>
> When Portable-VirtualBox starts, it checks to see if the drivers are
>   installed. If they are not it will install them before running
>   VirtualBox and will remove them afterward. Similarly,
>   Portable-VirtualBox checks to see if the services are running. If not,
>   it will start them and then stop them when it exits.

The result is a product not always running and with strange kernel errors.
There is another project (starting from Tekn0 observations) [Kquemu Portable](https://code.google.com/p/kqemu-portable-win/downloads/list)
and finally [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/getcurrent.html).